# use pkg command for babylonjs

Tags: package, executable, commonjs, pkg-config, babylonjs

I am trying to generate an executable with

```
pkg .
```

Therefore I added `"bin": "dist/src/main.js"` to the package.json. the build works as long as I am not including libraries. But if I use Babylonjs from the the node_modules, I get errors, because Babylonjs uses es6 syntax and I probably need to Transpile the code upfront as well?

I don't know how to do that. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is a transpiled version of babylon. that solved it:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babylonjs/v/4.1.0-beta.2